# question about optimization model

Tags: convex-optimization

[image: exercise is here]

It seems pretty odd to change one of the variable when trying to do some optimization.

Comment: Please edit your question using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553), avoid using images as it is not searchable.

Comment: I notice you deleted this post shortly after receiving an answer. **Don't do that.** It's unkind to those who took the time to answer your question and makes it look like you're trying to hide something.

Answer (score 1):

You want your volume to be $33$, hence you should not let it be an inequality. when we see $V$, we should directly replace it with $33$.

You do not want to minimize the gradient of the objective function, you want to minimize the objective function.

That is you want to minimize

$$\min _r\frac{66}r+2\pi r^2$$

$$s.t. r > 0$$